# Why doesn't TypeScript warn when a function is used with a different number of arguments as expected?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a vanilla JavaScript project in VS Code with `jsconfig.json` set up and the following example code:

```js
/**
 * @param {(arg: string) => void} nestedFunction
 */
function myFunction(nestedFunction) {
  // Some logic here
}

myFunction("text");       // Error gets highlighted
myFunction(() => {});     // Fewer arguments: error doesn't get highlighted
myFunction((a, b) => {}); // More arguments: error doesn't get highlighted and "a" is of type "any"
```

The same happens in a TypeScript file if I define the function like so:

```js
function myFunction(nestedFunction: (arg: string) => void) {
  // Some logic here
}
```

VS Code correctly highlights the error when passing a wrong type of argument to `myFunction` (a string), but it doesn't complain when passing a function that doesn't match the format of `nestedFunction`. Why?

In case it's needed, the `jsconfig.json` file is the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that JSDoc is meant for this level of type checking? Maybe using typescript would be more helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript and TypeScript support in VS Code is from [the builtin TypeScript Language Features extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features), which is just built on TypeScript.

#### When you use a function with fewer arguments than "expected"

I think this is a case of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters, which states:

> This is the expected and desired behavior. First, refer to the "substitutability" primer at the top of the FAQ

I think the "substitutability primer" being referred to is [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#substitutability), which states:

> Many answers relating to the type system make reference to [Substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This is a principle that says that if an object `X` can be used in place of some object `Y`, then `X` is a subtype of `Y`. We also commonly say that `X` is assignable to `Y` (these terms have slightly different meanings in TypeScript, but the difference is not important here).
>
> In other words, if I ask for a `fork`, a `spork` is an acceptable substitute because it has the same functions and properties of a `fork` (three prongs and a handle).

The function being used in a place that is typed for a function with more parameters can safely ignore extra parameters. For example:

> ```js
> let items = [1, 2, 3];
> items.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
> ```
>
> This is isomorphic to the example that "wanted" an error. At runtime, `forEach` invokes the given callback with three arguments (value, index, array), but most of the time the callback only uses one or two of the arguments. This is a very common JavaScript pattern and it would be burdensome to have to explicitly declare unused parameters.

There's much more elaboration in the rest of that wiki page that you can read if you're interested.

#### When you use a function with more arguments than "expected"

From my basic experimentation, this is only acceptable in TypeScript files if you make the "extra" parameters [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters). Quoting from the same wiki section linked above:

> Function signatures are always read from the caller's perspective. If `forEach` declared that its callback parameters were optional, the meaning of that is "`forEach` **might call the callback with 0 arguments**". [...] `forEach` always provides all three arguments to its callback. You don't have to check for the `index` argument to be `undefined` - it's always there; it's not optional.

In JavaScript files, it seems that TypeScript doesn't care- or at least that VS Code's builtin TypeScript Language Support extension doesn't care.

Note though that from the dev tooling side of things, TypeScript 5.4 will provide a quick fix suggestion to add parameters to the function if it is called with more arguments than the declaration's signature defines. See [the related release notes section](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4/#quick-fix-for-adding-missing-parameters).